# Probability measure of a homethetic transformation of a closed half space in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $P$ a probability measure over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\tau > 0$. Let's define the half space 
$$
A_{\omega, \alpha} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle x, \omega\rangle \leq \alpha\}, \text{ and } B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle\tau x, \omega\rangle \leq \alpha\}.
$$
Could I say that $P(B) = P(A_{\omega, \alpha})$. I did the following:
nne has 
\begin{align*}
P(B) &= P(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle\tau x, \omega\rangle \leq \alpha\})\\
&= P(\{\frac{y}{\tau} \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle y, \omega\rangle \leq \alpha\})\\
&= P(\{{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle y, \omega\rangle \leq \alpha\}),
\end{align*}
where in the last equality I used the fact that $\frac{y}{\tau} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ iff ${y}{} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Am I right in my math. reasoning?

Thanks,

S

Comment: What does $\omega >\leq \alpha$ mean?

Comment: Here $<\omega, x> = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \omega_i$ denotes the inner product of $\omega$ and $x$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the Euclidean norm.

Comment: ah, I see. the mathjax is $\langle y, \omega \rangle$, “\langle , \rangle” by the way.

Comment: I will edit it, thanks